# How to go back one page using useNavigate and pass data to that page : react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to 'go back' one web page using useNavigate but I also need to pass data to that page also.
When I use:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate(-1, {state: {data: myData});
```

I am able to navigate to the previous page, but I do not receive the data.
This page I am trying to go back to is actually the home page so if i try:

```
navigate('/', {state: {data: myData});
```

I am able to navigate to the home page and receive the data.  I would like to use

```
navigate(-1, {state: {data: myData});
```

as it would be more convenient to scale my website moving forward.  Help please.

Comment: When using a navigation delta, i.e. `-1` the `navigate` function doesn't take an `options` parameter. Route state only really makes sense when navigating forward.  Can you explain the use case more clearly? What is the issue you are trying to solve for?

Comment: After login i want to go back on success login with a welcome user message. So is there any possibility to pass message on go back.